# How to read raspberry pi temperature from script on an Arduino to control fan

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, temperature

I am working on a school project that includes both my raspberry pi and aruduino, I have made a temperature script that allows me to monitor the pi's current temperature and I am wondering if I can read this output from my arduino in order to control a fan's speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually to it all with the Raspberry Pi. Control you fan with a PWM value that will then turn on and off a MOSFET.

If you really have to do it with the Arduino, the "simple noob" way of doing this is to send a PWM pulse output from the Pi and analog read it from the Arduino. From there, do the same as you would do with the Pi.

Comment: Using the PWM value worked, the fan will now turn on if the components get too hot.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use serial communication. If you have to use the Arduino, then Dat Ha is right, PWM is the easiest.